# gulp.src from a separate file doesnt work

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to write a gulpfile as follows :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
// other dependencies go here ....

// source of files 
var inputs = require('./asset_source.js');

// a simple task
gulp.task('css', function () {
    gulp.src(inputs.css)
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(maps.init())
    .pipe(concatCss('libs.css'))
    .pipe(maps.write('../srcmaps'))
    .pipe(plumber.stop())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
});

// the watcher
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./asset_source.js', ['css']);
});

// default task
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

And the source of assets (asset_source.js) file is something like this :

```
module.exports = {
    css: [
     'path/to/a/file.css',
     'path/to/another/file.css',
     .......
     .......
    ],
    js: [
     'path/to/a/file.js',
     'path/to/another/file.js',
     .......
     .......
    ]
};
```

Now I run the app with by just typing **gulp** in the console and it starts in a browser thanks to browsersync. I have all the css,scss,js assets listed in the asset_source.js file which is in the same directory as the gulpfile.js. What I want to achieve is if I append or remove a value to/from either of the arrays in asset_source.js, the concerned task should run while the gulp is already running. In this case **css** should be running on any change to **asset_source.js** with its updated content.

But instead it doesnt do so. Even if there is a change in the asset_source file, gulp uses the initial content and runs the task. However if run **gulp css** in a separate terminal, it works.

Please help me where I am going wrong or if it is even possible. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if you just put this line : var inputs = require('./asset_source.js');  into the top of your css task if that will make it more dynamic.  Because your inputs variable is not being updated when you make a change to assets_source.js  it is read once when the gulpfile is run.

Comment: Exactly, thats the case! I have tried almost everything to make it as much dynamic as possible. But this asset_source file would not update unless gulp is quit and start again or run the tasks in another terminal. Any clue how to get over this without quitting the gulp or run the task in separate terminal ?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Put the     var inputs = require('./asset_source.js');    line into the 'css' task as the first line just before the gulp.src line.  And comment it out from where you presently have it.

Comment: yup already did that before ! That didnt work too. Still loads the old instance. Any gulp plugin can do this ? I have tried using [require-uncached](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-uncached) as well.